# Magento Product quantity entry

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento am total beginner. I started three weeks ago because I should create a shop. Now arises a question? How can I clear the field for order amount at item if it is not needed. As to this page http://www.diedruckerei.de/Visitenkarten,-8,5-x-5,5-cm,-4-4-farbig.htm?websale8=diedruckerei&pi=PVKV844&ci=005896

Button for cart should remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Stefan you can create same thing in Magento Using `Creating a Configurable Product`.

you have to create the configurable Product in Magento and solve your this problem.

Configurable Products let your customers select the variant they desire by choosing options.  For example, you sell t-shirts in two colors and three sizes.  You’d create the six variants as individual products (with their own skus) and then add these six to a configurable product from where customers can choose size and color, then add to cart.  If desired you could also have customers search for “red medium t-shirt” and land on the specific page for this variant. To [Read More Regarding Configurable Products.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer,

so i now it, but i make a drop-down for the total pieces and so i dont need the qty. I only need the Button Add to Cart. Can i remove the qty field?

Comment: yes you can manage that thing

Comment: and how I can make this

Comment: see that like and follow the steps